# How do I query for posts by custom meta and those that have been stickied?

Tags: query, wpdb, sql

I realize how clumsy and inefficient this query is but SQL is not my strong point. I use the following query to pull the latest 8 events from a custom post type called Event Posts. However, I also need to include in those 8 posts any posts which have been stickied. Because of some very complicated client needs which exceed the capabilities of wp_query I've been forced to craft the query by hand and use wpdb to execute it.

Could someone help me add to this query to also grab stickied posts?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, mt2.meta_value AS start_time, mt3.meta_value AS end_time, mt4.meta_value AS start_date, mt5.meta_value AS event_id, mt6.meta_value AS event_meta, mt7.meta_value AS event_thumb
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key = 'event_start_time')
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id AND mt3.meta_key = 'event_end_time')
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt4.post_id AND mt4.meta_key = 
'event_start_date')
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt5 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt5.post_id AND mt5.meta_key = 'event_id')
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt6 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt6.post_id AND mt6.meta_key = 'event_meta')
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt7 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt7.post_id AND mt7.meta_key = 'event_thumbnail_url')
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (7) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'espresso_event'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'event_start_date'
AND (mt1.meta_key = 'event_start_date'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) >= '" . date('Y-m-d') . "') )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) ASC, CAST(mt2.meta_value AS TIME) ASC
LIMIT 0, 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky posts are kept in a serialize array in an option in `$wpdb->options` with the `option_name` of `sticky_posts`. So you will need to pull that option and add an `OR` to the query.

```
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');

$qry = "... OR {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (".implode(',',$sticky).")";
```